# React MUI DataGrid align column data and header with type "number"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, datagrid, mui-x-data-grid

I'm using MUI in my react project. When I set the type of a column to `type: "number"` the column header and data align to the right. I reproduced the issue at the simple example from MUI documentation: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-leftpad-f7r2v?file=/demo.js)

The third column `age` has `type: "number"` and everything alignes to the right. But other columns with default types - to the left.

How can I align header and data of a column with `type: "number"` to the left?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

this list of type you can choose :

```
declare type GridNativeColTypes = 'string' | 'number' | 'date' | 'dateTime' | 'boolean' | 'singleSelect' | 'actions';
```

and list of aligns you have :

```
declare type GridAlignment = 'left' | 'right' | 'center';
```

how can you use :

```
  columns={[
          {
            field: 'id',
            flex: 1,
            minWidth: 150,
            type:"number",
            align:'left'
          },
]}
```

[codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-microservice-2oi5i?file=/demo.js)

and for more information, it is a list of properties you can use in column object :

```
interface GridColDef {
    field: string;
    headerName?: string;
    description?: string;
    width?: number;
    flex?: number;
    minWidth?: number;
    hide?: boolean;
    sortable?: boolean;
    resizable?: boolean;
    editable?: boolean;
    sortComparator?: GridComparatorFn;
    type?: GridColType;
    valueOptions?: Array<string | number | {
        value: any;
        label: string;
    }>;
    align?: GridAlignment;
    valueGetter?: (params: GridValueGetterParams) => GridCellValue;
    valueFormatter?: (params: GridValueFormatterParams) => GridCellValue;
    valueParser?: (value: GridCellValue, params?: GridCellParams) => GridCellValue;
    cellClassName?: GridCellClassNamePropType;
    renderCell?: (params: GridRenderCellParams) => React$1.ReactNode;
    renderEditCell?: (params: GridRenderEditCellParams) => React$1.ReactNode;
    headerClassName?: GridColumnHeaderClassNamePropType;
    renderHeader?: (params: GridColumnHeaderParams) => React$1.ReactNode;
    headerAlign?: GridAlignment;
    hideSortIcons?: boolean;
    disableColumnMenu?: boolean;
    filterable?: boolean;
    filterOperators?: GridFilterOperator[];
    disableReorder?: boolean;
    disableExport?: boolean;
}
```

Comment: sorry my answer is a little long but it may help newcommers

Comment: lets say I have a column with either "active" and a "not active" value. How can I create a conditional style rendering for those cell values? E.g. blue background for active users and red for non actives. I'd appreciate any help heaps!

Comment: we can add type:"actions" for it, too

Answer (score 15):

To align header and column data, use both `headerAlign` and `align` props for GridColDef.

```
const columns: GridColDef[] = [
{
  field: 'age',
  headerName: 'Age',
  flex: 1,
  editable: false,

  headerAlign: 'center',
  align: 'center'
}]

const rows = ...

<DataGrid
  rows={rows}
  columns={columns}
/>
```